# Mathematica: inverse IntegerDigits with FromDigits

Tags: binary, wolfram-mathematica

Using IntegerDigits and ToCharacterCode I convert a String a 2D Table of binary. Now I need to reverse this and all the Mathematica Help claims that FromDigits is the inverse of IntegerDigits. Yet I cannot get back to my original string. Here's my code:

```
ConvTextTo[s_String]:= IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode[s],2, 8];
ConvTextFrom[l_List]:= FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[l, 2]];
```

This returns gibberish and I cannot figure out why. If FromDigits is indeed the inverse of IntegerDigits, why doesn't this work, for god's sake? This is driving me insane, I googled this for an hour now, I cannot find a solution. I've tried whatever I could think of, nothing seems to produce a result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you want compare `ConvTextFrom[ConvTextTo["abc"]]` to `ConvTextFrom[#] & /@ ConvTextTo["abc"]`

Answer (score 0):

You did well but there is just a little more to it. First you need to Map (/@) FromDigits onto each binary sequence, representing one character. Second Apply (@@) StringJoin to the result of FromCharacterCode to get the original concatenated String. Apply replaces the Head of any expression with a new function that is applied to its arguments.

In general on reducing frustration :-) try giving the problem a rest and coming back to it, or just asking for help as you did. It's an elegant language and will gradually become instinctive.

```
In[9]:= string1 = 
  "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy white dog.";

In[10]:= ToCharacterCode@string1

Out[10]= {84, 104, 101, 32, 113, 117, 105, 99, 107, 32, 98, 114, 111, \
119, 110, 32, 102, 111, 120, 32, 106, 117, 109, 112, 101, 100, 32, \
111, 118, 101, 114, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 108, 97, 122, 121, 32, \
119, 104, 105, 116, 101, 32, 100, 111, 103, 46}

In[11]:= IntegerDigits[%10, 2, 8]

Out[11]= {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
  0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
  1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
  1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}

In[14]:= FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ %11

Out[14]= {84, 104, 101, 32, 113, 117, 105, 99, 107, 32, 98, 114, 111, \
119, 110, 32, 102, 111, 120, 32, 106, 117, 109, 112, 101, 100, 32, \
111, 118, 101, 114, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 108, 97, 122, 121, 32, \
119, 104, 105, 116, 101, 32, 100, 111, 103, 46}

In[15]:= FromCharacterCode@# & /@ %14

Out[15]= {"T", "h", "e", " ", "q", "u", "i", "c", "k", " ", "b", "r", \
"o", "w", "n", " ", "f", "o", "x", " ", "j", "u", "m", "p", "e", "d", \
" ", "o", "v", "e", "r", " ", "t", "h", "e", " ", "l", "a", "z", "y", \
" ", "w", "h", "i", "t", "e", " ", "d", "o", "g", "."}

In[16]:= StringJoin @@ %15

Out[16]= "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy white dog."
```